# compress the data inside my json file to binary

Tags: python, json, binary, compression, gzip

I'd like to convert my json file to a binary format. example(gzip) because I want the data binary.
as I searched, I found there is a way to do it with gzip.

import json
import gzip

```
> def compress_data(data):
>     # Convert to JSON
>     json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
>     # Convert to bytes
>     encoded = json_data.encode('utf-8')
>     # Compress
>     compressed = gzip.compress(encoded)
```

this didn't work for me as I have a file not just an object in json,
so, is there a way to compress the data inside my file to binary (in python ).
thanks a lot!

Comment: gzip doesn't really turns your data into binary format in any meaningfule way. It just compresses a file and produces a (usually) smaller compressed file (which is binary, that is non textual). Is it what you want?

Comment: in fact I want to turn my json data into binary but i don't know how, is there any approaches? thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Or rather what's the goal of this "converting to binary"? How do you intend to use the binary data you get after conversion?

Comment: what i want to do is convert a json file to binary, because at the end I want to compare that json file having binary data to a .proto file in terms of size. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your goal is to compare different data representations in terms of storage size.

One of the options is just compressing existing json file with gzip, either through python or directly. See here how to compress existing file with gzip module https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Another option is loading json file and then storing is as a pickle file, using pickle module

```
with open("file.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(obj, f)
```